# ScheduledExecutorService not triggering correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

I am attempting to have a method triggered after a delay with the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateTDDBRejections(), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It should wait for the delay to pass, trigger the "UpdateTDDBRejections" method, which is in another, Runnable, class, which will print out a phrase and then sleep and then print the phrase again, etc, etc.

It does not do this, it simply prints the phrase and then stops.

However when I set it up like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
{
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // do stuff
           System.out.println("garbage garbage garbage");
      }
    }, 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It operates as one would expect from the ScheduledExecutorService. I was under the impression that since I am using Java 8.4 that I would not have to add a TimerTask to make this coordinate in the way I want. Any suggestions? Or am I simply not able to call other Runnable classes with the ScheduledExecutorService?

EDIT: This is the UpdateTDDBRejections class.

```
public class UpdateTDDBRejections implements Runnable
{
   UpdateTDDBRejections()
   {
       System.out.println("garbage garbage garbage");
   }
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the implementation of `UpdateTDDBRejections` look like?

Comment: @TavianBarnes added. It isn't very glorious, I'm just trying to call the class right now so I can get it working and then its going to get more added to it. This is, "proof of concept" to show that I can do the thing.

Comment: Um, you should move the work to the `run()` method, not the constructor.  The constructor runs only once, when you do `new UpdateTDDBRejections()`

Comment: @TavianBarnes omfg thank you! I wasn't thinking! Yepp that was it!

Comment: The code is wrong, regardless of which Java version you use, so I don’t see the connection to Java 8. Further, I don’t see how “TimerTask” is involved.

Comment: @Holger offending tags removed. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the `run` method that is executed repeatedly. Try the following:

```
public class UpdateTDDBRejections implements Runnable
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       System.out.println("garbage garbage garbage");
   }
}
```

Note that since you're using Java 8, you could do

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("garbage garbage garbage"),
                         5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

If you want the constructor to run (which is perhaps what you tried with `new UpdateTDDBRejections()` you need to do:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(UpdateTDDBRejections::new, 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oooo! Brilliant! Yes that was EXACTLY what I was going for! Thank you!

Comment: If I wanted to pass variables to that constructor, how would I set it up?

Comment: The scheduleAtFixedRate takes a Runnable, and a Runnable.run does not take arguments. Perhaps use a Callable?

Comment: Hmmm, I was under the impression that Runnable could take arguments and just not return things? I've seen it posted in several places here on SO...

Comment: Nope. It's a functional interface, and the method in question is `public void run()`, which clearly does not accept arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77345/discussion-between-senex-subconscious-and-aioobe).